# try to send string to rs232 - But without success

Tags: c#, printing, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I tried to print through Windows Mobile to TSC TA200 printer, but without success.

This is my code:

```
private static void SendSampleData()
{
    SerialPort portZ = new SerialPort("COM1", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One); // I also tried 9600
    portZ.Open();
    portZ.Write("Hello World");
    portZ.Write(new byte[] { 0x0A, 0xE2, 0xFF }, 0, 3); // I tried to send bytes
    portZ.Close();
}
```

I also tried to change the COM Port to COM2, COM3...and play with the baudrate to 9600, 4800...but still no success.

> There is no error but does not print anything - nothing happens!

Comment: You close the port before it could transmit the data.  Never write it like that, open the port when you start your program, don't close it until it ends.  If you absolutely have to then you must loop until BytesToWrite drops to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the printer does not understand your code.

Try with a null-modem RS232 cable connected to your PC and open Hyperterminal (or TeraTerm) to capture the COM port used on the PC. Then look what happens inside ther terminal program on PC when your run your program on the device.

What Mobile Device are you using? Many of them use COM ports for internal hardware and so COM1 may not the right one. Look at registry of device at Drivers/active for the loaded drivers and the COM ports (name) and the index entries (they make then the COM1, COM2 etc).

And many Windows Mobile devices do not have a RS232 port but may support an external USB-to-RS232 adapter. these may use different port names than 'COM' for the virtual serial port.